# What might cause OpenLayers plugin to hang on windows 8.1?

Tags: openstreetmap, qgis-2, qgis-openlayers-plugin, windows-8

I'm trying to add OpenStreetMap layer to the map through OpenLayers plugin and then application hangs.
The problem occures on Windows 8.1 QGIS 2.0.1. On Windows 7 everything works correct.
Does anyone know what might be problem and how to fix it or how to add OSM another way?

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. Is it possible that your machines have different firewall settings?

Comment: It works fine in my windows8.

Comment: Not so easy but you may debug your plugin like that http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/How_to_debug_QGIS_Plugins

Comment: please fire up qgis from the command line, so you can see what happened in the background.